# SharePoint 2010 Content Organizer Issue

Tags: sharepoint

I have a document center and a custom content type. I can create the organizer rule and it routes the documents appropriately.

However, the issue that I am having seems to be with the automatic folder creation. When I create the rule, I specify only "%2" for the folder name. The column that I am using is a month. I've tried this two ways, having the value as a number or text, but I get the same issue. The folder is created as 'float; 2.00000000' or 'string; 12' instead of just 2 or 12.

Can anyone assist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should never create folder with number. Please use any prefix it will not create this problem. I have also face this problem and this was the best solution I have found for it.